# Native crash at /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so on kitkat android 4.4

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I get "Native crash at /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so" errors many times for android 4.4+. There was no such problem before 4.4.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/ja3gxx/ja3g:4.4.2/KOT49H/I9500XXUFNB4:user/release-keys'
Revision: '10'
pid: 32504, tid: 32595, name: xxx.yyy >>> com.xxx.yyy <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000001
r0 83c80e70 r1 00000000 r2 00000001 r3 00000000
r4 7ea6d230 r5 7a806d20 r6 7ea6d234 r7 00000000
r8 7ea6d264 r9 7ea6d274 sl 00000000 fp 83c80e70
ip 00000001 sp 7a806d00 lr 75e63a97 pc 75e63a9c cpsr 68030030
d0 3f8000003f800000 d1 3e80000000000001
d2 42a20000430c8000 d3 0000005142a30000
d4 0000008cfffffffb d5 0000005142a20000
d6 0000000700000000 d7 000000013f800000
d8 0000000000000000 d9 0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 4016800000000000 d17 0000000000000000
d18 402e000000000000 d19 0000000000000000
d20 3fd8000000000000 d21 0000000000000000
d22 0000000000000000 d23 0000000000000000
d24 402e000000000000 d25 0000000000000000
d26 3fd8000000000000 d27 0000000000000000
d28 4016800000000000 d29 0000000000000000
d30 09800261096d825c d31 09a4c26a09924265
scr 88000010

backtrace:
#00 pc 00b53a9c /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#01 pc 001dbc1b /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#02 pc 001dbe67 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#03 pc 001da09f /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#04 pc 0000d280 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#05 pc 0000d418 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

code around pc:
75e63a7c f7fd4628 a807ff92 ff8ff7fd 0008f104
75e63a8c db9ef691 f6854630 9806dca4 68024639
75e63a9c 47986813 f6714630 9806d843 aa092101
75e63aac 46497241 46289009 ff54f7ff 46289a08
75e63abc a020f8cd f7fd9207 9b07ff70 f104bb23
75e63acc a9060060 fd34f7fe f7fda807 a806ff66
75e63adc da61f671 f855e789 93093b04 1e50695a
75e63aec b9186158 a9094640 fcf4f7ff 68819807
75e63afc d1f0428d f691e7e3 a805db63 db92f649
75e63b0c f691e004 e770db23 e7ef685d e8bdb00b
75e63b1c b5708ff0 4604b09e 460da810 d801f67f
75e63b2c f67ea817 2300dffe a8104629 93099308
75e63b3c f7ff930a 1d20fc83 f6709003 6e25dff1
75e63b4c f855e01f aa063b04 a910a80c f7ff9306
75e63b5c 9e0cff01 900c2000 9607a80c ff1df7fd
75e63b6c 2a009a07 809df040 f7fda807 e008ff16

code around lr:
75e63a74 462b4649 fefaf7fe f7fd4628 a807ff92
75e63a84 ff8ff7fd 0008f104 db9ef691 f6854630
75e63a94 9806dca4 68024639 47986813 f6714630
75e63aa4 9806d843 aa092101 46497241 46289009
75e63ab4 ff54f7ff 46289a08 a020f8cd f7fd9207
75e63ac4 9b07ff70 f104bb23 a9060060 fd34f7fe
75e63ad4 f7fda807 a806ff66 da61f671 f855e789
75e63ae4 93093b04 1e50695a b9186158 a9094640
75e63af4 fcf4f7ff 68819807 d1f0428d f691e7e3
75e63b04 a805db63 db92f649 f691e004 e770db23
75e63b14 e7ef685d e8bdb00b b5708ff0 4604b09e
75e63b24 460da810 d801f67f f67ea817 2300dffe
75e63b34 a8104629 93099308 f7ff930a 1d20fc83
75e63b44 f6709003 6e25dff1 f855e01f aa063b04
75e63b54 a910a80c f7ff9306 9e0cff01 900c2000
75e63b64 9607a80c ff1df7fd 2a009a07 809df040
```

I could only created the situation on genymotion emulator(Samsung Galaxy S4) when I tried to play mp4 video:

```
06-25 08:31:19.647: I/chromium(2652): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
06-25 08:31:19.715: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:19.751: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:19.779: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:19.803: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:19.827: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:19.851: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:19.871: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:19.919: E/chromium(2652): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(69)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:C0EBA4B9]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : glBindTexture: target was GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES
06-25 08:31:19.919: E/chromium(2652): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(3142)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:C0EBA4B9]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : glProduceTextureCHROMIUM: target was GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES
06-25 08:31:19.919: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:19.991: I/qtaguid(191): Tagging socket 37 with tag 3f500000000(1013) for uid 10059 failed errno=-13
06-25 08:31:20.167: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:20.247: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:20.323: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:20.371: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:20.435: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:20.491: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:20.895: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): SniffFFMPEG
06-25 08:31:20.895: I/FFmpegExtractor(191): android-source:0xb8b91830
06-25 08:31:20.895: D/FFMPEG(191): android source begin open
06-25 08:31:20.895: D/FFMPEG(191): android open, url: android-source:0xb8b91830
06-25 08:31:20.895: D/FFMPEG(191): ffmpeg open android data source success, source ptr: 0xb8b91830
06-25 08:31:20.895: D/FFMPEG(191): android source open success
06-25 08:31:21.563: I/NuCachedSource2(191): new range: offset= 3406048
06-25 08:31:21.567: I/qtaguid(191): Tagging socket 39 with tag 3f500000000(1013) for uid 10059 failed errno=-13
06-25 08:31:21.579: I/qtaguid(191): Untagging socket 37 failed errno=-13
06-25 08:31:24.979: I/NuCachedSource2(191): ERROR_END_OF_STREAM
06-25 08:31:25.031: I/NuCachedSource2(191): new range: offset= 0
06-25 08:31:25.079: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(191): Reconnecting...
06-25 08:31:25.231: I/NuCachedSource2(191): retrying a previously failed read succeeded.
06-25 08:31:25.271: I/FFMPEG(191): Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'android-source:0xb8b91830':
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):   Metadata:
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):     major_brand     : mp42
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):     minor_version   : 1
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):     compatible_brands: mp42avc1
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):     creation_time   : 2014-06-24 11:20:49
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):   Duration: 00:01:14.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 397 kb/s
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 640x360, 334 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 2500 tbn, 5k tbc (default)
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):     Metadata:
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):       creation_time   : 2014-06-24 11:20:50
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):       handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 59 kb/s (default)
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):     Metadata:
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):       creation_time   : 2014-06-24 11:20:50
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFMPEG(191):       handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFmpegExtractor(191): FFmpegExtrator, url: android-source:0xb8b91830, format_name: mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, format_long_name: QuickTime / MOV
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFmpegExtractor(191): list the formats suppoted by ffmpeg:
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFmpegExtractor(191): ========================================
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[00]: mpeg
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[01]: mpegts
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[02]: mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[03]: matroska,webm
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[04]: asf
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[05]: rm
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[06]: flv
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[07]: swf
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[08]: avi
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[09]: ape
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[10]: dts
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[11]: flac
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[12]: ac3
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[13]: wav
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[14]: ogg
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[15]: vc1
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): format_names[16]: hevc
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFmpegExtractor(191): ========================================
06-25 08:31:25.275: V/FFmpegExtractor(191): major_brand tag is:mp42
06-25 08:31:25.275: D/FFmpegExtractor(191): suppoted codec(h264) by official Stagefright
06-25 08:31:25.275: D/FFmpegExtractor(191): suppoted codec(aac) by official Stagefright
06-25 08:31:25.275: D/FFMPEG(191): android source close
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFmpegExtractor(191): sniff through BetterSniffFFMPEG success
06-25 08:31:25.275: D/FFmpegExtractor(191): ffmpeg detected media content as 'video/mp4' with confidence 0.08
06-25 08:31:25.275: I/FFmpegExtractor(191): support container: video/mp4, but it is caching data source, Don't use ffmpegextractor
06-25 08:31:26.211: I/NuCachedSource2(191): new range: offset= 3406048
06-25 08:31:26.211: I/qtaguid(191): Tagging socket 37 with tag 3f500000000(1013) for uid 10059 failed errno=-13
06-25 08:31:26.227: I/qtaguid(191): Untagging socket 39 failed errno=-13
06-25 08:31:26.951: I/NuCachedSource2(191): ERROR_END_OF_STREAM
06-25 08:31:26.987: I/MediaFocusControl(577):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@52b19560com.android.org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerListener@52824660
06-25 08:31:26.987: D/MediaPlayer(2652): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
06-25 08:31:26.991: I/AwesomePlayer(191): setDataSource_l(URL suppressed)
06-25 08:31:27.039: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:27.107: E/eglCodecCommon(2652): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
06-25 08:31:27.191: A/libc(2652): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 2652 (isefe.gazeteler)
06-25 08:31:27.295: I/DEBUG(106): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-25 08:31:27.295: I/DEBUG(106): Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:4.4.2/KOT49H/eng.buildbot.20140524.041238:userdebug/test-keys'
06-25 08:31:27.295: I/DEBUG(106): Revision: '0'
06-25 08:31:27.295: I/DEBUG(106): pid: 2652, tid: 2652, name: isefe.gazeteler  >>> com.barisefe.gazeteler <<<
06-25 08:31:27.295: I/DEBUG(106): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106): backtrace:
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):     #00  pc 011cc329  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so (cc::GLRenderer::DrawStreamVideoQuad(cc::DirectRenderer::DrawingFrame const*, cc::StreamVideoDrawQuad const*)+111)
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106): stack:
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd18  00000438 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd1c  0000025e 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd20  43858000 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd24  b97ba3b0  [heap]
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd28  b97ba3c0  [heap]
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd2c  984aa285  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so (cc::GLRenderer::SetBlendEnabled(bool)+47)
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd30  b970d8a8  [heap]
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd34  00000be2 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd38  984ac03d  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so (cc::GLRenderer::GetVideoStreamTextureProgram(cc::TexCoordPrecision)+9)
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd3c  98d9eeb8  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd40  b934d998  [heap]
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd44  b97ba398  [heap]
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd48  00000001 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd4c  984ac325  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so (cc::GLRenderer::DrawStreamVideoQuad(cc::DirectRenderer::DrawingFrame const*, cc::StreamVideoDrawQuad const*)+107)
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd50  b934d998  [heap]
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd54  00000001 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):     #00  bf8bfd58  000000ca 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd5c  bf8bfd80  [stack]
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd60  3f800000 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd64  00000002 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd68  bf8bfd90  [stack]
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd6c  b934d998  [heap]
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd70  00000000 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd74  0000010b 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd78  00000438 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd7c  984b4008  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so (cc::GLRenderer::DoDrawQuad(cc::DirectRenderer::DrawingFrame*, cc::DrawQuad const*)+286)
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd80  00000168 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd84  000000ca 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd88  44870000 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd8c  44178000 
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd90  b934d998  [heap]
06-25 08:31:27.519: I/DEBUG(106):          bf8bfd94  bf8bfea8  [stack]
06-25 08:31:27.675: I/BootReceiver(577): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_00 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
06-25 08:31:27.695: D/dalvikvm(577): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1712K, 21% free 14837K/18732K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
06-25 08:31:27.703: W/ActivityManager(577):   Force finishing activity com.barisefe.gazeteler/.NewsBrowserActivity
06-25 08:31:27.723: W/MediaFocusControl(577):   AudioFocus   audio focus client died
06-25 08:31:27.723: I/MediaFocusControl(577): AudioFocus  removeFocusStackEntry(): removing entry for android.os.BinderProxy@529ab19c
06-25 08:31:27.723: I/ActivityManager(577): Process com.barisefe.gazeteler (pid 2652) has died.
06-25 08:31:27.727: I/AwesomePlayer(191): Prepare cancelled while waiting for initial cache fill.
06-25 08:31:27.727: W/MediaPlayerService(191): native_window_api_disconnect returned an error: Broken pipe (-32)
06-25 08:31:27.727: W/InputDispatcher(577): channel '52a12384 com.barisefe.gazeteler/com.barisefe.gazeteler.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
06-25 08:31:27.727: E/InputDispatcher(577): channel '52a12384 com.barisefe.gazeteler/com.barisefe.gazeteler.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-25 08:31:27.731: W/InputDispatcher(577): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '52a12384 com.barisefe.gazeteler/com.barisefe.gazeteler.MainActivity (server)'
06-25 08:31:27.731: I/WindowState(577): WIN DEATH: Window{52a12384 u0 com.barisefe.gazeteler/com.barisefe.gazeteler.MainActivity}
06-25 08:31:27.735: I/WindowState(577): WIN DEATH: Window{5295de8c u0 com.barisefe.gazeteler/com.barisefe.gazeteler.NewsBrowserActivity}
06-25 08:31:27.743: D/dalvikvm(2749): Late-enabling CheckJNI
06-25 08:31:27.755: I/ActivityManager(577): Start proc com.barisefe.gazeteler for activity com.barisefe.gazeteler/.MainActivity: pid=2749 uid=10059 gids={50059, 3003}
06-25 08:31:27.827: I/qtaguid(191): Untagging socket 37 failed errno=-13
06-25 08:31:27.843: D/dalvikvm(2749): GC_CONCURRENT freed 58K, 4% free 3497K/3636K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 12ms
06-25 08:31:27.879: D/dalvikvm(2749): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9K, 4% free 3676K/3796K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-25 08:31:27.887: I/dalvikvm-heap(2749): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.660MB for 5241612-byte allocation
06-25 08:31:27.895: D/dalvikvm(2749): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 8795K/8916K, paused 9ms, total 10ms
06-25 08:31:27.899: D/dalvikvm(2749): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 8795K/8916K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 4ms
06-25 08:31:27.967: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2749): Google Play services is missing.
06-25 08:31:27.975: D/dalvikvm(2749): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads695412881.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
06-25 08:31:27.975: D/Zygote(190): Process 2652 terminated by signal (11)
06-25 08:31:27.979: W/linker(2763): libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
06-25 08:31:27.995: D/dalvikvm(2763): DexOpt: load 2ms, verify+opt 1ms, 158252 bytes
06-25 08:31:28.003: D/dalvikvm(2749): DexOpt: --- END 'ads695412881.jar' (success) ---
06-25 08:31:28.003: D/dalvikvm(2749): DEX prep '/data/data/com.barisefe.gazeteler/cache/ads695412881.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 26ms
06-25 08:31:28.007: I/Ads(2749): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("82E22535BB949544CBEEF894029F0CE9") to get test ads on this device.
06-25 08:31:28.011: I/Ads(2749): Starting ad request.
06-25 08:31:28.015: V/WebViewChromium(2749): Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {52828044}
06-25 08:31:28.015: I/chromium(2749): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
06-25 08:31:28.019: I/BrowserProcessMain(2749): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
06-25 08:31:28.031: D/libEGL(2749): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
06-25 08:31:28.031: D/(2749): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb9301bc0, tid 2749
06-25 08:31:28.031: W/chromium(2749): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
06-25 08:31:28.047: D/libEGL(2749): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
06-25 08:31:28.047: D/libEGL(2749): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
06-25 08:31:28.099: D/dalvikvm(2749): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 229K, 4% free 9191K/9500K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
06-25 08:31:28.103: I/dalvikvm-heap(2749): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.466MB for 2536932-byte allocation
06-25 08:31:28.107: D/dalvikvm(2749): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 11668K/11980K, paused 5ms+0ms, total 7ms
06-25 08:31:28.263: W/EGL_genymotion(2749): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-25 08:31:28.267: E/OpenGLRenderer(2749): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
06-25 08:31:28.267: E/OpenGLRenderer(2749): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
06-25 08:31:28.271: E/OpenGLRenderer(2749): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
06-25 08:31:28.271: E/OpenGLRenderer(2749): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
06-25 08:31:28.271: D/OpenGLRenderer(2749): Enabling debug mode 0
06-25 08:31:32.755: I/Choreographer(2749): Skipped 267 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): Rebuild removed 3 windows but added 2
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): java.lang.RuntimeException: here
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.rebuildAppWindowListLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8011)
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.rebuildAppWindowListLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7947)
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.handleAnimatingStoppedAndTransitionLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8691)
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner(WindowManagerService.java:9205)
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedLoop(WindowManagerService.java:8163)
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8105)
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.access$300(WindowManagerService.java:157)
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:7139)
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): This window was lost: Window{5295de8c u0 com.barisefe.gazeteler/com.barisefe.gazeteler.NewsBrowserActivity}
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mDisplayId=0 mSession=Session{52b692b4 2652:u0a10059} mClient=android.os.BinderProxy@529978b4
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mOwnerUid=10059 mShowToOwnerOnly=true package=com.barisefe.gazeteler appop=NONE
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mAttrs=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#10 ty=1 fl=#1810180 pfl=0x8 wanim=0x10302a1}
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): Requested w=1080 h=1776 mLayoutSeq=520
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mBaseLayer=21000 mSubLayer=0 mAnimLayer=21005+0=21005 mLastLayer=21015
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mToken=AppWindowToken{5299aeb4 token=Token{5292a720 ActivityRecord{5298fec8 u0 com.barisefe.gazeteler/.NewsBrowserActivity t7}}}
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mRootToken=AppWindowToken{5299aeb4 token=Token{5292a720 ActivityRecord{5298fec8 u0 com.barisefe.gazeteler/.NewsBrowserActivity t7}}}
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mAppToken=AppWindowToken{5299aeb4 token=Token{5292a720 ActivityRecord{5298fec8 u0 com.barisefe.gazeteler/.NewsBrowserActivity t7}}}
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mViewVisibility=0x0 mHaveFrame=true mObscured=false
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mSeq=0 mSystemUiVisibility=0x0
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mGivenContentInsets=[0,0][0,0] mGivenVisibleInsets=[0,0][0,0]
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mConfiguration={1.0 ?mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw360dp w360dp h567dp 480dpi nrml port finger qwerty/v/v dpad/v s.5}
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mHasSurface=true mShownFrame=[0.0,0.0][1080.0,1776.0] isReadyForDisplay()=false
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mFrame=[0,0][1080,1776] last=[0,0][1080,1776]
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mSystemDecorRect=[0,75][1080,1776] last=[0,75][1080,1776]
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): Frames: containing=[0,0][1080,1776] parent=[0,0][1080,1776]
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     display=[0,0][1080,1776] overscan=[0,0][1080,1920]
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     content=[0,75][1080,1776] visible=[0,75][1080,1776]
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):     decor=[0,75][1080,1776]
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): Cur insets: overscan=[0,0][0,0] content=[0,75][0,0] visible=[0,75][0,0]
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): Lst insets: overscan=[0,0][0,0] content=[0,75][0,0] visible=[0,75][0,0]
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): WindowStateAnimator{52b684d0 com.xxx.yyy/com.xxx.yyy.HedeBrowserActivity}:
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):   mSurface=Surface(name=com.xxx.yyy/com.xxx.yyy.HedeBrowserActivity)
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):   mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN mLastHidden=true
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):   Surface: shown=false layer=21015 alpha=1.0 rect=(0.0,0.0) 1080.0 x 1776.0
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577):   mGlobalScale=1.0 mDsDx=1.0 mDtDx=0.0 mDsDy=0.0 mDtDy=1.0
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): mExiting=false mRemoveOnExit=false mDestroying=true mRemoved=false
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): Current app token list:
06-25 08:31:32.791: V/WindowManager(577):   Display 0
06-25 08:31:32.791: V/WindowManager(577):   #1: Token{52a0cb88 ActivityRecord{52a0cad8 u0 com.xxx.yyy/.MainActivity t7}}
06-25 08:31:32.791: V/WindowManager(577):   #0: Token{529b44ec ActivityRecord{52991f2c u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher t1}}
06-25 08:31:32.791: W/WindowManager(577): Final window list:
06-25 08:31:32.791: V/WindowManager(577):   #0: Window{529c3590 u0 SearchPanel}
06-25 08:31:32.791: V/WindowManager(577):   #1: Window{52990efc u0 NavigationBar}
06-25 08:31:32.791: V/WindowManager(577):   #2: Window{52980744 u0 StatusBar}
06-25 08:31:32.791: V/WindowManager(577):   #3: Window{529cf5d8 u0 Keyguard}
06-25 08:31:32.791: V/WindowManager(577):   #4: Window{5290d2a8 u0 KeyguardScrim}
06-25 08:31:32.791: V/WindowManager(577):   #5: Window{5296d0cc u0 Application Error: com.xxx.yyy}
06-25 08:31:32.791: V/WindowManager(577):   #6: Window{529a7b38 u0 com.xxx.yyy/com.xxx.yyy.MainActivity}
06-25 08:31:32.791: V/WindowManager(577):   #7: Window{52964704 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
06-25 08:31:32.791: V/WindowManager(577):   #8: Window{52919a38 u0 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper}
06-25 08:31:32.803: I/ActivityManager(577): Displayed com.xxx.yyy/.MainActivity: +5s72ms
06-25 08:31:32.939: I/chromium(2749): [INFO:simple_index_file.cc(397)] Simple Cache Index is being restored from disk.
06-25 08:31:32.943: I/Ads(2749): JS: Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache (http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html:0)
06-25 08:31:32.943: I/chromium(2749): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache", source: http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-25 08:31:32.943: I/Ads(2749): JS: Application Cache Checking event (http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html:0)
06-25 08:31:32.943: I/chromium(2749): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-25 08:31:33.143: I/Ads(2749): JS: Application Cache NoUpdate event (http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html:0)
06-25 08:31:33.143: I/chromium(2749): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-25 08:31:33.199: W/ContextImpl(2749): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) } android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:517 com.google.analytics.tracking.android.AnalyticsGmsCoreClient.connect:82 com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.connectToService:330
06-25 08:31:33.199: W/GAV3(2749): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
06-25 08:31:33.199: I/GAV3(2749): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
06-25 08:31:33.199: W/ActivityManager(577): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) } U=0: not found
06-25 08:31:35.007: W/InputMethodManagerService(577): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2652 uid 10059
06-25 08:31:35.011: W/Binder(763): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
06-25 08:31:35.011: W/Binder(763): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 08:31:35.011: W/Binder(763):     at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
06-25 08:31:35.011: W/Binder(763):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
06-25 08:31:35.011: W/Binder(763):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
06-25 08:31:35.011: W/Binder(763):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I couldn't control the html coming from url so I need a solution that works on application site.
Thanks.

Comment: Please post relevant code to your problem. Looking at only logs is not much helpful.

Comment: The two stack traces you gave us are slightly different.  One fails with address 0x1 and one with 0x0.  THat makes me suspect a null pointer in the C code.  The second stack trace shows that its happening in cc::GLRenderer::SetBlendEnabled(bool) so I would suspect some rendering structure is NULL when it shouldn't be.  Which makes sense when you're rendering video.  No idea how to fix it, but I'd check all values passed to the webview for nulls.  If you're adventurous you can try to figure out what's wrong by looking at the AOSP C++ code there.

Comment: The first stacktrace I often got from the google play crash report and can't get more detail. Second stacktrace is the case I can succeed to produce on emulator. For the second stacktrace I only open a url from a webview with mp4 inside it and when I click to mp4 above error is happening.

Comment: Does it happen with a different mp4 (especially from a different encoder) as the target?  Could be something about that particular file which exposes a bug in a codec.

Answer (score 14):

I'm experiencing a very similar issue with my app on Android 4.4.2.

I found this thread on Chromium support forum that identifies the issue I think is 100% relevant to me, and may be relevant to you.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334992

**334992 - WebView on Nexus 10 with stock KitKat 4.4.2 crashes when scrolling up or down**

Basically, when attempting to scroll (up-down, or left-right) on long content that has not fully loaded, you can reliably make the webview control crash.

It only happens on some devices (like it happens on Galaxy S5 for me, but not Galaxy Mega), but always seems to affect Android 4.4.2.

Check out that Chromium thread, and I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes Scott, I following that thread but still no solution. Turning off the hardware acceleration may solve that but some videos do not play when turning the hardware acceleration off.

Comment: All six different devices with this crash run Android 4.4. Five are Galaxy, and one is LG.

Answer (score 4):

There's a chromium bug link on this line:

```
06-25 08:31:19.919: E/chromium(2652): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(69)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:C0EBA4B9]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : glBindTexture: target was GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES
```

which is pointing to : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=242999

Most probably, the GLES implementation on genymotion is missing OES_EGL_image_external*
*http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused from a graphic memory bug, so you can try to disable some CSS using any  -CSS webkit-transform like " -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1); ". (I saw this same bug on iOS if you load too many data in GPU memory).

Comment: the solution not always by adding the -webkit in my case change the unit from rem to pixel