# Catch WebView (chrome) crashes with lower Android API

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, crash

So we use Webviews as a main feature in our application therefore we got lots of crashes caused of the native process it uses .

most crashes like base.apk and chrome.apk with no other explication like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407411/native-crash-at-system-lib-libwebviewchromium-so-on-kitkat-android-4-4)

we have implemented `onRenderProcessGone` as [google docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onRenderProcessGone(android.webkit.WebView,%2520android.webkit.RenderProcessGoneDetail)) , and we believe that now we can catch these crashes on newer devices >= api 26

How about older APIs do we have a similar interface ? or another approach to gracefully catch these crashes and give the user a chance to recover before that ugly crash.

Comment: Did you find any alternatives in Api < 26 in these 4 years?